# More readable way of not matching negated words in a sentence

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to not match negated word in a sentence such as adjective with `not, never` for example. Currently I used character level negation. Example for `not` `^(?:[^n]+|n(?:$|[^o]|o(?:$|[^t]|\w)))`. Is there an easy way (more readable) of doing this for one or many negation words (`not, never, any, nobody, ......`). Here is a code for `not` negation:

```
package main

import(
 "fmt"
 "regexp"
)

func main (){
    sentence:="he is not satisfied"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`^(?:[^n]+|n(?:$|[^o]|o(?:$|[^t])))\ssatisfied`)
    fmt.Println(re.FindAllString(sentence, -1))
    sentence="he is satisfied"
    fmt.Println(re.FindAllString(sentence, -1))
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, for performance reasons (though the Go regexp parser is not particularly performant anyway), Go's regexp package does not support lookahead/lookbehind, so there is no great way to do this using regular expressions.

Regular expressions aren't a great fit for this anyway, though. It requires a very complex expression to do a very simple match. If I were implementing something similar, I would probably just split the string on spaces/punctuation and do my own matching. Easier to work with and likely better performance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Please can you elaborate more how this can be achieve, when we have to translate regular expressions in others language to Go program. Thank you.